# Stuck on a system call with variables

Tags: ruby, windows, backup

I'm writing a ruby script that will automate backing up my laptop to my ssh server.  I seem to be stuck on a system call though.

```
$x = "C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe"

###calibre library###
$library = "C:\\Users\\maste_000\\Documents\\Calibre Library"
system($x, "a library.7z", $library, " -r")
```

I'm trying to call the exe 7z and create a file called library.7z, from the directory pointed to by $library.  No matter how I arrange this though I keep getting a 7z command error.  I'm assuming this has something to do with how I'm performing the system call though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess that you want this:

```
system($x, 'a', 'library.7z', $library, '-r')
```

That would give you the same effect as this at the command prompt:

```
C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe a library.7z "C:\Users\maste_000\Documents\Calibre Library" -r
```

Assuming, of course, that I haven't completely forgotten how quoting works with the Windows command line.

The space in `$library` won't matter when you use the multi-argument form of the [`system`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-system); part of the reason that you use this version of `system` is to avoid all the weird quoting that you need when the shell is in the way. The main thing is that you probably need to separate `'a'` and `'library.7z'` so that they are two arguments rather a single argument with a space as the second character; without that separation you'd be saying this:

```
C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe "a library.7z" "C:\Users\maste_000\Documents\Calibre Library" -r
```

and that doesn't look right.

Comment: That worked.  It seems similar to what I did... Is there a reason as to why 'a' needed to be separated from 'library.7z'?

Comment: @Jacobm001: I think you commented while I was adding some discussion about what's going on. Have a look at the last paragraph of my updated answer, let me know if anything is still unclear.

Comment: ha, yes I did.  It makes more sense now.  Thanks for your help, I realize it was a fairly trivial issue...